# How to draw text on top of image HTML?

Tags: php, html

I need to draw text in top of the image this the look like

[image]

when the page load i need to display price in side the photo.I try it like this

```
<button class="btn btn-danger" id="buy-btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".package-buy-modal">BOOK NOW</button>
<img id="price-tag" style="position: relative;width: 100%; /* for IE 6 */" src="<?php echo base_url()?>assets_profile/img/price.png">
<h2 style="-o-transform: rotate(32deg);-moz-transform: rotate(32deg);-webkit-transform: rotate(32deg);">$<?php echo $car_data['Charges']; ?></h2>
```

But it didn't work as i expected.how can i do this.if there is another easy way to this ?

Comment: I think it might help to tell us what is expected.

Comment: I think you could use the image as a `background-image` via css.

Answer (score 4):

Here is an example of using `background-image` within a div so that you can put more inside the div, ie)text

HTML:

```
<div id='image' src='https://i.stack.imgur.com/1DZ6X.jpg'>
    <h2 id='price'>Price: $10</h2>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#image {
    width:243px;
    height:163px;
    background-image:url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/1DZ6X.jpg');
}
```

[check it out here](http://jsfiddle.net/sgrAM/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Add a `z-index` value to the `<img>` and the `<h2>`. For example, `z-index:98` on the `<img>`, and `z-index:99` for the `<h2>`. (A higher value because you want it on top).

I would also recommend moving all styles to a css file, rather than use the inline `style` attribute.